# By downloading picture's file-header, how to obtain enough information?

Tags: python, excel

I need to download some pictures from a picture server every day. This server adds thousands of pictures daily, and many pictures have large size. Since the server does not support thumb pics and any pic-description, I have to download the pictures completely to know whether this picture is the one I need. However, my network bandwidth is very low, so it cost considerable time to download every picture. Moreover, the server has strict network flow controlling, thus, I may only download less than 100 pictures every day if the pictures are all large. 
I search some related articles and find that picture's file-header contains many useful information, so this is my plan:

1. Use python code to download all pictures' file-header. If I only download file-header, the network flow will be very small, so I can download all pictures' file-header on the server.
2. Analyse every pictures' file-header and obtain enough information. From my searching, I know the picture's format(png/jpg/gif), size(XXX,XXX bytes), resolution(XXXX×YYY,such as 1920x1080) can be obtained from picture's file-header which is less than 1000 bytes. Maybe it is possible to get more information from picture's file-header, so if you know more, please help me.
3. Export the result to an Excel file.

Could you tell me the effective python code to achieve the above three demands?

Added on July 22:
This is some information I got from HTTP header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 22 Jul 2018 15:13:19 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 376386
Cache-Control: public,max-age=518400
Expires: Sat, 28 Jul 2018 15:13:19 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 22 Jul 2018 15:13:19 GMT
Vary: Origin
ETag: "5be42"
Connection: Keep-alive
```

Now I can get Content-Type and Content-Length from HTTP header. But it is not enough for me.
I searched and found someone said they could read the image's resolution(XXXX×YYY,such as 1920x1080) from the first 100 bytes of the pic-file data.(100 here is only the maximum number, somebody even said he can get the resolution from the begin 30 bytes of the pic-file data.) I think it is true because many pics I downloaded not-finished can display the resolution and the top of the pic. 
Moreover, maybe there is a way to generate thumb without downloading complete pic? I'm not sure it is possible or not, but I think if it can be done, it will be very useful.

Comment: This is not a "we write code on demand site" but you show what you have done and people offer help to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL library and use getdata.

Comment: Do getdata of Pil need to download complete image? Because the strict network flow controlling, I need to get the image's resolution from the begin part of file-data, which means the downloading is not complete, only the begin part will be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible or are there image headers at all? When I do something like

```
curl -I https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bb/Png-logo.png
```

to get HTTP headers, I don't see an image size or anything like that:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 21 Jul 2018 17:35:26 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 811068
Connection: keep-alive
X-Object-Meta-Sha1Base36: tup6ux1u98mkbw32ta64fna0hqw6y09
Last-Modified: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 23:18:32 GMT
Etag: 1f427f6758058528cc0d474a14ee6dc1
X-Timestamp: 1380842311.64879
X-Trans-Id: txdbd33b3337fb497694bd8-005b536ebb
X-Varnish: 185288243, 96001562 108570149, 528370630
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1), 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1), 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 34
X-Cache: cp1062 pass, cp3038 hit/2, cp3039 miss
X-Cache-Status: hit-local
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Analytics: https=1;nocookies=1
X-Client-IP: 87.152.115.72
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Age, Date, Content-Length, Content-Range, X-Content-Duration, X-Cache, X-Varnish
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' data:; font-src data:; img-src data: https://upload.wikimedia.org/favicon.ico; media-src data:; sandbox; report-uri https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?reportonly=1&source=image&action=cspreport&format=json&
X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' data:; font-src data:; img-src data: https://upload.wikimedia.org/favicon.ico; media-src data:; sandbox; report-uri https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?reportonly=1&source=image&action=cspreport&format=json&
X-Webkit-CSP-Report-Only: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' data:; font-src data:; img-src data: https://upload.wikimedia.org/favicon.ico; media-src data:; sandbox; report-uri https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?reportonly=1&source=image&action=cspreport&format=json&
```

Even if there is such a thing, the limit of 100 would probably affect the image headers as well.

Comment: Sorry, my past description was not accurate. The pictures' file-header I meant contains the HTTP-header you gave here and the first 100 bytes of the pic-file data. You can get the picture's format(png/jpg/gif), size(XXX,XXX bytes) from the HTTP-header. I searched and found some people said they can get the resolution(XXXX×YYY,such as 1920x1080) from the begin part of pic-file data. I think it is true because many pics I downloaded not-finished can display the resolution and the top of the pic. Maybe there is a way to generate thumb without downloading complete pic.

Comment: Um, yeah... did you try curl -I with your URL? Did you mention the name of the website somewhere? What is the name of the header with the image size? Does this limit of 100 only apply to fully loaded images? So, after reaching the limit, can you calculate the image size at least theoretically, if you knew how to code it or is it a waste of time?

Comment: The header info has been pasted on the topic I edited just now, you can see the new topic content. The limit of 100 images is just for example. I meant, if the images are all large, there will be just less than 100 images. The image size of the limit could not be calculated, because I tried several times and the result changed every time. If I download on the morning and the images are not large, I can download hundreds of images. But on the night, the network flow controlling is very strict, so if the images are large, I can only download less than 100.

Comment: OK, from the headers you mentioned, you can't even calculate the image size. Please look at Ajay Shah's answer. I'm out.

Comment: I think the image size is Content-Length. The size of the image I downloaded is just the number of Content-Length. Now I just need to know how to get the resolution from the begin 30 bytes of the pic-file data. So do you know how to just download the begin part of the pic-data, not download completely? (Such as downloading the begin 50 bytes)